# Equal height issue in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 div container of col-md-6. First one contain half area of page and socond contain 2 div. The problem is that in 2nd container area not equal to first div.

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6" ><img src="http://ste.india.com/sites/default/files/2015/12/05/438674-5-12-2015-show-gh8-o.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>

<div class="col-md-6" >

<div col-md-12>
<img src="http://ste.india.com/sites/default/files/styles/zm_700x400/public/2015/12/06/438831-dpz6dcab-14s.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>

<div class="col-md-12"  >
<img src="http://ste.india.com/sites/default/files/styles/zm_700x400/public/2015/12/06/438831-dpz6dcab-14s.jpg" class="img-responsive"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0ao8tvk/)

CSS:

```
.group{width:100%; display:table;}
.one{width:50%; background:#999; display:table-cell; }
.two{width:50%; background:#ff0000; display:table-cell;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
</div>
```